# How do I get visibility into Node/IO.js/V8 GC behavior?

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

I'd like to be more aware of how often node's GC is executing and how long it's taking to execute. I'm probably shoving more data than I should be into memory and experiencing some painful pauses. It'd be nice to be able to see what's going on as we experiment and make changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer for V8 via Chrome, but I'm pretty sure it's easily adaptable for V8 via Node:

1) Run Chrome passing `--prof` into V8 flags:

`/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium  --no-first-run --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -dt 'chrome-dev-profile')  --no-sandbox --js-flags="--logfile=%t.log --prof"`

The important parts are `--js-flags="--prof"` and  `--no-sandbox`

2) Then you will find a bunch of files called "isolate-0x*-v8.log". Usually you'll be interested in the largest one, but it may require some digging.

3) Open `about:tracing` in Chrome and drag 'n drop a log file onto it.

4) Click on the V8 link on the left side:

[image]

5) You'll then get a sunburst chart of the profiling results from V8.

[image]

Comment: Mid-answer I'm thinking this may give you the execution data, but no insight on GC. That may require another tracing approach like https://www.chromium.org/developers/creating-v8-profiling-timeline-plots